# Exclude blank images in JQuery carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm trying to work with a bit of code that pulls the list of new book titles from our library catalog and then uses that to create a JQuery carousel. It builds the url for the image src for each title using the book's ISBN number. The issue is that not every book on the new title list has an ISBN and some that do don't have a cover image. Is there something I can add that will make it so any titles that don't have a cover image do not get added to the carousel? I have limited JQuery experience so I haven't been able to figure it out.

```js
$.each( records.HitlistTitleInfo, function () {
    $("<img/>").attr("src", coverURLprefix + this.ISBN[0] + coverURLsuffix).attr("alt",
    this.author).attr("title", this.title).addClass("cloudcarousel").appendTo("#carousel1");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest method be to only retrieve books with an ISBN rather that later remove the books that don't?

Comment: How would I do that though? The code retrieves books from the New Titles list, generated by the catalog, which includes those with or without ISBNs. Also, some books that have the an ISBN don't have a cover image.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(record.HitlistTitleInfo).not( function(index, element) {
    var isbn = this.ISBN[0]
    return isbn == null || isbn.length == 0; // true means it's removed
}).each( {
    $("#carousel1").attr("src", coverURLprefix + this.ISBN[0] + coverURLsuffix)
        .attr("alt", this.author)
        .attr("title", this.title)
        .addClass("cloudcarousel");
});
```